# Get Facebook user friends sorted by relevance

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way getting user friends list from Facebook as sorted on Facebook site?

For example when I tag someone in a picture, the friends offered by Facebook are sorted by relevance. Also the friends on the chat are sorted by relevance.

Is there a field which I can order by to achieve that or do I need to get parameters on each user and calculate some kind of friends ranking?

Comment: That was my assumption, I hoped someone did find a way.

Comment: Well, there is something you could use, but nobody exactly knows how FB sorts by relevance... AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could use the `mutual_friends_count` field of the `user` table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) to do some kind of own sorting. You could query this via FQL:

```
SELECT uid,first_name, last_name,mutual_friend_count FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY mutual_friend_count DESC
```

But currently this is not working well: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/242368225968716/